Is the BBC website out of compliance with the UK cookie regulations regarding consent and nudging techniques?
The United Kingdom's Information Commissioner's Office (ICO) requires websites to make it as easy to reject non-essential cookies as to accept them and also outlaws "nudging techniques", which the BBC itself has reported on, yet the BBC.co.uk website seemingly is in violation by having its cookie banner provide a simple button to agree to all cookies and another button to go to a settings page in order to reject cookies.  The BBC was not named in the ICO's public notice to top websites about being in violation.  Since the BBC is one of the most famous UK websites, is associated with government, and has in the past been looked to by others & businesses for methods to comply with prior 2012 cookie regulations, it seems that the ICO would almost certainly be aware what the BBC is doing and yet the ICO has made no statement about the BBC despite the seeming violations.  At face value, the BBC website looks to be in violation but perhaps there is a legal nuance that makes it compliant. Is the BBC cookie consent method somehow not in violation of the ICO rules about making it as easy to reject as accept cookies as well as avoiding "nudging" behavior?


I think you are right, +1.  I cannot really add to your analysis, but this is really common.  I think I have seen it on government sites, BICBW.

In the years immediately after GDPR, most websites I saw conformed to the law, requiring the same number of clicks (generally one) to opt out as to opt in. But more recently, a much greater number of websites are starting to require many more clicks to opt out, and making this harder by other means (multi-stage dialogues, smaller buttons, required scrolling, lower-contrast text, "accept" buttons which close the dialogue while discarding preferences you have set). The law hasn't changed, but as far as I can tell, site owners are realising that the law is not really enforced.
